# facebook like on html <map>

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

I have an image with facebook like thumb. I've created a html map tag, and now my area tag have src to facebook page but i want make this link to really like my facebook profile.

I found this  - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/ 
this tutorial produces a like button but i want assign like action to my src atrribute on area tag in map tag.

How can i assign like action to src attribute on area tag?
or
How can i assign like action to onclick() event on area tag?

Comment: you can´t. you can only use the like button - everything else would be "click-jacking".

Comment: thanks for the reply